# Change flash player generated from an external javascript on select change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a player at 128kbps generated from a javascript external file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://shoutcast.mixstream.net/js/external/flash/s2.vanavilfm.com:8560:1::cc0000:F4A213:::1"></script>
```

and another player at 64kbps.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://shoutcast.mixstream.net/js/external/flash/s2.vanavilfm.com:8000:1::cc0000:F4A213:::1"></script>
```

I wanted my users to select bit rate using:

```
<select id="bitrate" name="bitrate">
  <option value="2">128 Kbps</option>
  <option value="1">64 Kbps</option>
</select>
```

So that when option 128kbps is selected only the player at 128kbps is displayed and played then vice versa using jquery..

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<select id="select">
    <option selected="selected">Choose</option>
    <option id="1">128</option>
    <option id="2">64</option>
</select>

<div id="sound1">
    128 <!-- 128kbps code here -->
</div>
<div id="sound2">
    64 <!-- 64kbps code here -->
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#select').change(function() {
   $('div').hide();
   $('#sound' + $(this).find('option:selected').attr('id')).show();
});​
```

Optional CSS

```
div{
    display:none;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
}

#sound1{
    background-color:red;
}

#sound2{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/pYvxe/**

Comment: I tried adding the scripts inside the divs and only the first div(sound1) is being displayed correctly.. the sound2 does not..